# Rails deeply nested form with nested_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am using [this cool gem ryanb nested_forms](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), but I can't get it to work correctly...

I have two levels of nested forms.

```
class Etude
    has_many :phases

class Phase
    has_many :affectations

class Affectation
```

Basically, to make things simple, I have a table of phases, and for each phase I have a table cell where I put its nested table of affectations. I use `<%= f.object.id %>` to generate a unique id for every nested table, so I can use data-target.

It works fine for the first nesting (many phases in etude), however I can't put the Affectations in the Phases in the tbody. 
He're my ode

*_phases.html.erb*

```
<%= nested_form_for @etude, :method => :post, :remote => true do |f| %>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tableau_phases">
    <thead>
        blablabla
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <%= f.fields_for :phases, :wrapper => false %>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- I use an other table tag otherwise new entries would appear after the "add_phase" link -->
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr><td>
        <%= f.link_to_add t("add_phase"), :phases, :data => { :target => "#tableau_phases" } %>
    </tr></td>
</table>
<% end %>
```

*_phase_fields.html.erb*

```
<tr>
    My fields
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <table id="<%= f.object.id %>" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover liste-intervenants">
        <thead>
            stuff
        </thead>
        <tbody><% f.fields_for :affectations %></tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
        <%= f.link_to_add "Ajouter un intervenant", :affectations, :data => { :target => "##{f.object.id}"} %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

*_affectation_fields.html.erb*

Just some pretty simple `<tr><td></td></tr>` stuff

**The problem :**

After I click the link to add a new affectation, it doesn't put the stuff in he table, but creates an extra div. He're what it looks like in the DOM

```
<table id="8354u3r1jh534g2fh">
    <thead>headers</thead>
    <tbody>EMPTY !!!</tbody>
    <div class="fields"> Stuff is added there and not in the tbody !</div>
</table>
```

It's weird cause I do have a `:data => { :target => "##{f.object.id}"}` that should handle inserting the date in tbody (I have checked, and this code actually outputs the good thing)

*Note : It does work perfectly well for the first level of nested forms (:phases in @etude)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, along with other problems I found on the way :

**FIX for original question** : I forgot the `:wrapper => false` for the SECOND level of nested forms

_phase_fields.html.erb

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="5">
    <table id="<%= f.object.id %>" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover liste-intervenants">
        <thead>
            stuff
        </thead>
        <tbody><% f.fields_for :affectations, :wrapper => false %></tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**PROBLEM 2** : now I still have weird stuff happening. For instance, when I have this on my frontend

```
Etude
  Phase 1
    [nothing]
  Phase 2
    [>> I Click "link_to_add" to add a new nested child "Intervenant 2.1"]
```

then the result becomes

```
Etude
  Phase 1
    [Intervenant 2.1]
  Phase 2
    [nothing]
```

The relevant piece of code is in *_phase_fields.html.erb*

```
    <%= f.link_to_add "Ajouter un intervenant", :affectations, :data => { :target => "##{f.object.id}"} %>
```

Now it would seem `"##{f.object.id}"` remains the same even for different "nested child". Is this actually a bug from the gem ?

**FIX for problem 2**

Actually, the ID generation should be done using `f.index` as suggested by the [rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-One-to-many).

**PROBLEM 3**

The nested-nested form don't generate the good ID elements for dynamically added fields !

*_affectation_fields.html.erb*

==> `<%= f.xxxx %>` Will generate something like `etude[phases_attributes][new_phases][affectations_attributes][1415653508668][nb_jeh]`. Problem is the [new_phase] which is not replaced by the appropriate generated phase ID

**FIX for Problem 3**

in each partial, either wrap `<tr>` inside a `<tbody class="fields">` or if there is a single `<tr>`, add the `.fields` class to it

**Explanation** :
Deeply Nested forms relies a lot on the gem nested_form regexp match&replace Javascript. And [the code](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/tree/master/vendor/assets/javascripts) uses jquery functions that will find DOM elements, first by going to the closest `.fields` ancestor.
For example : `link_to_remove` will go to the closest `.fields`, hide it, and also set the `_destroy` to true.